# How could I correct my code? The main goal of my code is initializing new string from another one, with just copying n first letters in C

Tags: c, terminal, computer-science

Can you give me advice to correct my code? It should initialize `new_string` from another string, with copying the `n` first letters from this string. Output should be string. But my code prints nothing. How can I fix it?

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char str[99];
    int n, i, len;
    printf("Enter a string:");
    scanf("%s", str);
    printf("enter n:");
    scanf("%i", &n);
    if (n > len) {
        n = len;
    }
    char *new_string = malloc(n + 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        new_string[i] = str[i];
    }
    new_string[i] = '\0';
    printf("STring:%s", new_string);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: strncp will do exactly that

Comment: Consider using the soon-to-be-standard [`strndup()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strndup) function. It has already been available for a long time on POSIX-compliant operating systems.

Comment: Close to a typo: you forgot to initialize `len`. Add `len = strlen(str);` between reading `str` and comparing `n` to `len`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`strncpy`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strncpy.htm) as suggested by [d.j.yotta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1513775/d-j-yotta) in the comments:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void)
{
    char str[100];
    printf("Enter string: ");
    /*
     * take spaces into account (optional),
     * prevent buffer overflow and
     * check return value of `scanf`
     */
    if (scanf("%99[^\n]", str) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: invalid input\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    int n;
    printf("Enter index: ");
    /* check return value of `scanf` */
    if(scanf("%d", &n) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: invalid input\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* initialize `len` */
    int len = strlen(str);
    if (n > len)
        n = len;
    char *new_str = malloc(n + 1);

    strncpy(new_str, str, n);

    printf("New string: %s\n", new_str);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Or you could make the changes explained in the following code's comments:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void)
{
    char str[99];
    printf("Enter string: ");
    /*
     * take spaces into account (optional),
     * prevent buffer overflow and
     * check return value of `scanf`
     */
    if (scanf("%99[^\n]", str) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: invalid input\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    int n;
    printf("Enter index: ");
    /* check return value of `scanf` */
    if(scanf("%d", &n) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: invalid input\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* initialize `len` */
    int len = strlen(str);
    if (n > len)
        n = len;
    char *new_str = malloc(n + 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        new_str[i] = str[i];

    /* you don't need `i` here */
    new_str[n + 1]= '\0';
    printf("New string: %s\n", new_str);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code is not easy to spot: you define two distinct local variables named `i`: one in the scope of the body of the `main` function in `int n,i, len;` and another one in the scope of the `for` loop: `for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { new_string[i] = str[i]; }`. The latter one goes out of scope at the end of the loop and the first one is used to set the null terminator `new_string[i]='\0';`. This `i` variable is uninitialized so the statement has undefined behavior and `new_string` is not properly null terminated.

There are other problems:

- you do not prevent buffer overflow in `scanf("%s",str);`
- you do not check for input or conversion failure in `scanf()`.
- `n` is uninitialized in `if (n > len) { n = len; }`
- you do not check for negative `n`.
- you do check for allocation failure after `char *new_string = malloc(n + 1);`
- you do not free `new_string` after use.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char str[100];
    int n, len;
    printf("Enter a string:");
    if (scanf("%99s", str) != 1)
        return 1;
    printf("enter n:");
    if (scanf("%i", &n) != 1)
        return 1;
    len = strlen(str);
    if (n > len) {
        n = len;
    } else
    if (n < 0) {
        n = 0;
    }
    char *new_string = malloc(n + 1);
    if (new_string == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "allocation failure for %d bytes\n", n);
        return 1;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        new_string[i] = str[i];
    }
    new_string[n] = '\0';
    printf("String: %s\n", new_string);
    free(new_string);
    return 0;
}
```

Note also some alternatives to copy at most `n` characters from a string:

```
// assuming new_string points to an array of at least n+1 bytes
strncpy(new_string, str, n);

// assuming new_string points to an array of at least n+1 bytes
snprintf(new_string, n + 1, "%s", str);
```

// assuming new_string points to an array of at least new_string_size bytes
//   and n has type int
snprintf(new_string, new_string_size, "%.*s", n, str);

Since you know that `n >= 0 && n <= len`, you can use `memcpy`:

```
memcpy(new_string, str, n);
new_string[n] = '\0';
```

You can also use the Posix function `strndup()` defined in `<string.h>` that combines allocating enough space, copying at most `n` bytes and setting the null terminator:

```
char *new_string = strndup(str, n);
```

`strndup()` will be part of the upcoming version of the C Standard (C2x) and is widely available on most platforms as it has been part of the Posix standard for more than 10 years.

Comment: Or since you know the length, no need to scan for end again, just `memcpy (new_string, str, n+1);`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: `memcpy (new_string, str, n+1);` is insufficient if `len > n`. Setting the null terminator is required. Answer amended with `memcpy()` without an extra scan. I would still recommend `strndup()` as a better approach and `strndup()` probably uses `memcpy` too.

Comment: You misunderstood. After all your checks on `len`, etc.., then as you show the other options, the `memcpy()` option is available as well with the deminimis saving of the function not checking for `'\0'` in the original again. I intended that to go after all length checks were satisfied and the `'\0'` in `str` validated.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: I agree that `memcpy(new_string, str, n)` has the advantage of not checking for a null byte in the source, but copying `n + 1` bytes would not necessarily set the null terminator because `n` can be smaller than the length of `str`, so `new_string[n] = '\0';` is required after `memcpy (new_string, str, n)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 100
int main(){
    char str[N];
    scanf("%s",str);
    char str1[N];
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
        str1[i]=str[i];
    }
    printf("%s",str1);
}
```

i think if you just want to copy a string in a new char variable you can do this please tell if you find anything wrong